# $(f(v),f(w))=(v,w)$ for a linear map $f$ on an Hilbert space

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces

Given an Hilbert space $H$ with product $(\cdot,\cdot)$ (linear in the second argument) and a $\mathbb{C}$-linear bijective map $f:H\to H$, why do we have $(f(v),f(w))=(v,w)$ for all $v,w\in H$?

Comment: You don't, not without additional assumptions on $f$: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_operator

Comment: Like what? :)..

Comment: Forget Hilbert spaces and just think about basic linear algebra. Do all matrices preserve the dot product of two vectors?

Answer (score 1):

You dont. Take $f(v)=2v$. Then $(2v,2v)=4|v|^2\neq|v|^2=(v,v)$ for $v \neq 0$. You need $f$ to be an isometry at the very least, so $|f(v)|^2=|v|^2$ holds as a necessarry condition.
Maybe someone else can suggest a sufficient condition.

Comment: It is also a sufficient condition, due to the polarization identity.